# Language sensitive title method (Plone, Archetypes, LinguaPlone)

Tags: internationalization, plone, plone-4.x, archetypes

I have a Plone site with internationalized content, using Archetypes and LinguaPlone.

Some of my objects (including folders) are language neutral, others are not. For generation of menus and navigation breadcrumbs, I'd like a method which

- returns the untranslated `Title()`, if the `Language()` is non-empty (because under this condition the `title` attribute is supposed to match the language), and
- returns a translation of the `Title()` otherwise (because the object is used for multiple languages, and I have a small set of affected strings).

I couldn't find any `*title*` method in the `Products.LinguaPlone` package; `pretty_title_or_id` is apparently language-agnostic.

Is there really no such method yet?

(Products.LinguaPlone 4.1.8, Products.CMFPlone 4.3.3, Products.ATContentTypes 2.1.14)

**Edit:** The affected objects are a limited number of folders (near the site root) whose titles very rarely change; most others have a non-empty `Language` (which will cause their `Title` not to be translated) or are non-folders (and won't have a known translation, I admit, but in those cases the original title would be used).  I could imagine to patch `pretty_title_or_id` accordingly, and I wonder about reasons not to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself:
It seems there is no such method because the *standard* set of metadata fields is not sufficient to support it.

For a small fixed set of languages, it might be a good solution to use `title_<lang>` metadata fields.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's going to work, because navigation menus will look at the index and metadata only, and there's definitely only one `Title` column in there, and you definitely don't want to not use the metadata there, for performance reasons.

You could, in theory, patch all templates you need (like the navigation portlet and the breadcrumb viewlet, but to be thorough, you'd need to patch *everything* that looks at `Title` anywhere, ever) to pass all their strings through the translation layer (basically adding `i18n:domain="..." i18n:translate=""`), and maintain your translations in a `.mo`/`.po` language file, but you'll have no way to change them at runtime. My gut feeling would be that that's patching over a conceptual problem with what lang-neutral items can and cannot do.

Comment: Well, I _do_ have the `Language` information in the metadata of my catalog ...
One of the most important uses is the generation of top and bottom menus, with a quite limited number of folders affected. Most other objects are either language-non-neutral, or non-folders (and thus not part of my menus).

Comment: Given the `Language` information as part of the metadata, and the affected folders are few _(see above)_ and their tiltes rarely change - what reason would there be not to patch the ubiquitous `pretty_title_or_id` method to handle languages this way? No need for `i18n:translate` attributes in combination with such a method, btw.

Answer (score 0):

When using LinguaPlone you create different content foe each language, so having a method that returns different language values doesn't make much sense...

If you want to do that with language independent content, you will need to patch objects' Title method and add your custom code there... Anyway this will have an impact in the catalog because only the default language content will be catalogged both for the index content and metadata, and will return strange results... So this is discouraged.

Comment: It would return different values for objects (i.e. almost exclusively folders) which are set "language neutral" _only_ (and whose default view executes a language-dependent search, btw). Did you read my comments to Ulrich's answer?

Comment: Yes, I read it. I meant that if you end patching the Title or pretty_title_or_id methods, you will face other issues like catalog search. Because catalog indexes the result of calling method Title on content objects, and if you patch that method to return different values depending on the users language, catalog will only store one of the values, the one that Title method returns when the catalog reindex is performed. Therefore when you search the site using the searchbox looking for that folder, you will only find it if you use the value of the title on the language it was indexed.

Comment: But the catalog doesn't care for `pretty_title_or_id` and instead simply uses the `Title` method, right? I never intended to do any changes to `Title`. And my use case are site menus, not general catalog searches.